# Implementing getElementByTagName recursively

Tags: javascript, algorithm, recursion

I'm trying to implement a function like getElementByTagName as a practice.
It seems there is a problem with recursive call but I can't spot what is wrong. In the second test case, I get 0 instead of 3. Could you shed some light on it please?

```js
function byTagName(node, tagName) {
  let nodes = [];
  if (node.children.legnth == 0){
      return [];
  }
  for(let i=0; i < node.children.length; i++){
      const element = node.children[i];
      if (element.nodeName.toLowerCase() == tagName){
          nodes.push(element);
      }
      nodes.concat(byTagName(element, tagName));
  }
  return nodes; 
}

console.log(byTagName(document.body, "h1").length);
// → 1
console.log(byTagName(document.body, "span").length);
// → 3
let para = document.querySelector("p");
console.log(byTagName(para, "span").length);
// → 2
```

```html
<h1>Heading with a <span>span</span> element.</h1>
<p>A paragraph with <span>one</span>, <span>two</span>
spans.</p>
```

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Are you sure you're not seeing a `0` instead of an `8`?

Comment: @slappy - I'm sure...that I **am** seeing a `0`, not an `8`. :-) Thanks. I guess it's that time in the afternoon when I have to put on my glasses.

Answer (score 1):

`concat` creates a new array. It doesn't mutate the original. Use `.push` instead.

```
nodes.push(...byTagName(element, tagName));
```

Comment: ...or use that new array: `nodes = nodes.concat(byTagName(element, tagName));` (but I'd do what slappy shows above).